# How can I transfer data after processing to another cluster using MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distcp

I am new to Hadoop. I want to write a single MR job which does some processing of the data and moves the result to another cluster. I am aware I can simply change the destination within the driver function, but I think it will transfer the data sequentially rather than in a distributed manner. Is there some way to call DistCp from within the MR job?

Comment: Why not `distcp` command in oozie workflow after MR job completion ?

Comment: I was looking to reduce the IO part of the app. If I use `distcp` command in oozie workflow after MR job completion I will be writing the output of MR Job and then reading it again to transfer it to the other cluster.